# How to create a custom UIView which has just a button and then can be used throughout the app placing it in different positions?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have already created a circular button which is a custom UIView.Here's the code:

```
 class HelpTips: UIView {

weak var hotSpot: UIButton!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let strongHotSpot = UIButton()
    hotSpot = strongHotSpot

    self.addSubview(strongHotSpot)
    hotSpotOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    hotSpotOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.TRLMHelpTipYellowColor()
    hotSpotOne.layer.borderColor = UIColor.TRLMHelpTipStrokeColor().CGColor
    hotSpotOne.layer.borderWidth = 1

    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hotSpot, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hotSpot, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hotSpot, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: hotSpot, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40)

    self.addConstraints([verticalConstraint, horizontalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

Now this same button is used throughout the app at several places but it's placed at different positions. So each View Controller will make use of that UIView. 
So technically the look of the button remains the same but the constraints for that button keep on changing depending on it's position. I want to follow DRY(Don't repeat yourself) technique here.
I have done this kind of thing before but the code was being repeated several times and was not efficient. How to go about this?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom navigation controller and store the view as a property in it. Every view controller will have access to the navigation controller, so they can just reference that property and time you need to use the view. Should keep it DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view using an xib. Add your UIButton as subview.

[This](http://sebastiancelis.com/2014/06/12/using-xibs-layout-custom-views/) tutorial will be helpful.